# Windowsでmdファイルを「JetBrainsのTOOLBOXから起動するIntelliJ IDEA」に関連付けたい

Tags: windows, intellij-idea

Windowsのエクスプローラでmdファイルをダブルクリックすると最新のIntelliJ IDEAが立ち上がるようにしたいです。
IntelliJ IDEAをTOOLBOXでupdateすると、update後のIDEAのパスが変わってしまい、update後のIDEAが起動できません。
どなたか解決の方法、よいアイデアがあればお教しえください。

IntelliJ IDEA単体でインストールすれば問題自体は解決すると思いますが、できればTOOLBOX経由で使いたいです。

Comment: これらの記事がヒントになるかもしれません。[JetBrains Toolbox in Windows to install IDEs to specific folders other than ones within drive C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47929313/9014308), [Where are the IDEs located on my hard drive?](https://toolbox-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000978804-Where-are-the-IDEs-located-on-my-hard-drive-), [Windows のファイル拡張子の関連付け](https://qiita.com/TsuneoNakanishi/items/5f0248c82bf073cf2868)

Comment: 教えていただいたページを確認しました。バイナリの場所はビルドの番号を含むフォルダの下でした。
TOOLBOXはその時点の「最新版」という概念がなさそうでした。IDEAはupdateしても１年間同じパスのようなので、IDEAを単独でインストールすることになりそうです。単独でインストールしたバイナリとファイルの関連付けをして、こちらを普段使いし、TOOLBOXは異なるバージョンが必要なときに使用することになりそうです。kunifさん、情報ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己回答です。

---

## TOOLBOXでインストールしたIntelliJ IDEAのパスの確認方法

TOOLBOXで表示される「IntelliJ IDEA」のアイコン(六角ナット)をクリックし、Settingsを選択します。
install locationの欄にパスが表示されます。showのリンクをクリックするとエクスプローラでファルダが開きます。

---

## ファイルの関連付け

エクスプローラでmdファイルのプロパティを開き、プログラムの変更でパスを指定すればmdファイルを関連付けられます。※GUIでファイルの関連付けをする一般的な方法です。

---

## 直接インストールしたIntelliJ IDEAをTOOLBOXから起動

TOOLBOXのメニューのManually　Installedに直接インストールしたIntelliJ IDEAが出てきました。これをクリックすると起動することができました。

---

## 最新版のIntelliJ IDEA

バージョンアップでIntelliJ IDEAのパスが変わります。最新版のラッパがないかと期待して探してみましたがありませんでした(もしあればそれを関連付けする)。
今のところパスが変わったら、パスを調べてファイルの関連付けをやり直すしか方法はなさそうです。